# getting java.lang.NullPointerException when using soap

Tags: java, php, soap

I am soapClient to access web service as follows.

```
$con = new SoapClient('wsdl url');
$array = array("apiRequestDetails" => array(
            "id" => "0000045399",
            "mobile" => "9843484142",
            "pin" => "b59c67bf196a4758191e42f76670ceba",
            "refNumber" => "222",
            "serviceCode" => "23",
            "trxnTraceId" => "1",
            "value" => "200.068879335"
    
    ));
$det = $con->__call('initiatePayment', $array);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($det);
```

I get following error
Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [S:Server] java.lang.NullPointerException in D:\xampp\htdocs\sharepoint\connection.php:25
Stack trace:

## 0 D:\xampp\htdocs\sharepoint\connection.php(25): SoapClient->__call('initiatePayment', Array)

## 1 {main}

thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\sharepoint\connection.php on line 25
Can anyone tell me what this error is and  how can i solve it.
thanks in advance

Comment: Calling `__call` directly _is deprecated_, check my answer, it contains a link to the man page

Comment: no java code here so why java tag?

Comment: @JqueryLearner though i am using php here the webservice that i am using is in java

Answer (score 1):

It's an unhandled exception. Try wrapping it in a try/catch block to find out the error. Also `__call()` is deprecated, you should be using `__soapCall()`.

```
try{
    $det = $con->__soapCall('initiatePayment', $array);
    print_r($det);
} catch(SoapFault $ex){
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I tried it too and it returns 'java.lang.NullPointerException' and I also have tried __soapCall() and also it gives the same error 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Comment: `__call` isn't deprecated. Calling it _directly_ is deprecated. For regular SOAP calls, the `__call` method is still being used

Comment: Also, read the docs for the `__soapCall` method (link in my answer): it's meant to be used in rather specific cases (non-wsdl, unknown SOAP action, different uri's etc...)